# AWS api gateway custom authorizer: access context variable in mapping template

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, custom-authentication

I have implemented a custom authorization module in `AWS API Gateway` using python. Basically it might return something like this:

```
access = {
    "principalId": "yyyyyyyy",
    "policyDocument" : {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Resource": [
                    "some-arn/*/GET/organisation"
                ],
                "Effect": "Allow"
            }
        ]
    },
    "context" : {
        "organization_id": "123"
    }
}
```

At the backend site i want to perform a GetItem on DynamoDb. The mapping template looks like this:

```
{   
    "TableName":"Organisation",
    "Key":{
        "id":{
            "S":"$context.authorizer.organization_id"
        }
    }
}
```

However, i am receiving an error, since the `context` variable seems to be empty:

```
Mon Jul 10 19:47:16 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {   ""
    "TableName":"Organisation",
    "Key":{
        "id":{
            "S":""
        }
    }
}

Mon Jul 10 19:47:16 UTC 2017 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"}
```

Any suggestions, what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing, I found out that the problem does only appear when testing using AWS console. This issue is also covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891631/how-to-test-api-gateway-methods-with-custom-authorizer-and-empty-context-author?rq=1). Hopefully AWS will solve this issue any soon.